# Is an object created first and then it's constructor executed?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

My question is that is

```
A a=new A();
```

here is the object created first and then the constructor method is called?
Or the object is created because the constructor method is called?

If the object is required to call the constructor, that means that the object should be created before the constructor is called and if I declare the constructor to be private (just to see if it works without the constructor), then I get an error.

Now if the constructor execution creates the object, I fail to understand how that logically works, I mean that without an object how can a method of the object can execute?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don't think this is useful in terms of asking about *both* C++ and Java

Comment: I removed C++ for now, let's talk about Java for now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Memory is allocated for the object before the constructor is called, yes.

You can think of it in terms of the following steps:

1. Memory is allocated for the object.
2. Various constructors are executed (always from the top of the hierarchy down to the most specific one, e.g., `Object`'s constructor is executed first, then whatever other super-classes you have, then the actual class's).
3. So the object already has memory for it, and it's being *initialized* by the constructors, not created.  The constructors are simply setting up the *state* of the object.
4. The object is unusable until the constructors are finished executing.

Point 4 actually isn't entirely true, because you can leak a reference to the object via passing `this` to another method within the constructor, but that's a bit of a fringe case.  It's kind of a fascinating phenomenon, because you can access things like `final` variables before they're initialized and retrieve two different values from them, depending on where in the execution they are.

Addressing the comments below: the constructor itself doesn't return anything.  It has a `void` return type.  How the variable actually receives the object isn't as straightforward as you might think, and it's a really good question.  You can read very detailed answers about this subject on the following Stack Overflow answers, which do a much better and thorough job than I could replicate here.

- [Can we have a return type for a constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3501693/1435657)
- [Why do constructors in Java not have a return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801500/why-do-constructors-in-java-not-have-a-return-type/6801537#6801537)

As a side note, as Peter Lawrey mentions in the comments, you are able to use the [Unsafe API](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) to create instances of an object without executing a constructor.  Based on [some other Stack Overflow discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501966/is-it-possible-to-produce-undefined-behavior-when-dereferencing-null-in-java), however, the general opinion seems to be that anything you do with `Unsafe` doesn't really qualify as normal Java behavior.

Comment: +1 Calling Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class) allows you to create an instance without calling a constructor.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah, I thought of that, but per some other discussions on Stack Overflow, people have generally said that you ought not consider `Unsafe` a valid use of the language since most of it is `native` code, which breaks the JLS.

Comment: @JeffGohlke It is not part of the JLS, just a library method.  It is not standard across JVMs either.  However it does show that for HotSpot/OpenJDK at least, it is a separate step.

Comment: Does the constructer return a reference to the object?

Comment: @user2319720 Actually, the constructor itself has a `void` return type.  This subject actually gets kind of complicated and isn't as straightforward a question as you might think.  You can think of it as the `new` keyword returning the object rather than the constructor.  There are a couple of good Stack Overflow Q&As that might help here.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3501693/1435657    http://stackoverflow.com/a/6801537/1435657

Answer (score 3):

You tagged the question with more than one language, you should pick one.

But the convention is to first allocate memory for the object and its fields, then run the constructor and then, *if applicable*, assign a reference to this new object to the variable `a`.

Some nuances exist. C#, for example, does things a little differently for value types.

1. Allocate memory for value type instance
2. Run constructor
3. Copy object, bit-by-bit, to the location `a` is pointing to.

This makes sure `a` never points to a partially-constructed instance of a value-type. It also makes sure that, if the constructor throws an exception, the memory location `a` points to is not left corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Answering for C++:

A new-expression (let's say `new A()`) is compiled as follows:

1 Check that the default constructor of `A` is accessible within the context; otherwise, signal a compilation error.

2a If class `A` has an overloaded allocation function `A::operator new()`, call it to obtain space for the object.

2b Otherwise, call the allocation function `::operator new()` to obtain space for the object.

3 Call the default constructor `A::A()` in the space obtained from the allocation function.

Answer (score 0):

Class has constructor which creates an object. You invoke constructor on a class not on an object, so new object is always created from class constructor.

Comment: constructor is not static, how can you invoke it on a class?

Answer (score 0):

The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. So **instantiating a class** means the same thing as **creating an object**, When you create an object, you are creating an **instance** of a class, therefore "instantiating" a class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `@dcastro` in general. However, I believe in both languages any instance fields that are assigned in-line are populated prior to the constructor being executed (or at least prior to the first line of code in the constructor). So you could make the conclusion that the object is created first, then the constructor is called.

```
class MyClass{
    final int value1 = 15;
    final int value2;

    public MyClass(){
          this.value2 = value1;
    }
}
```

In both languages, I believe `value2` will be set to 15. So add step `1a - populate in-line instance fields` to `dcastro's` answer.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I didn't comment on the *whole* procedure. There's much more to it than this. For example, the static constructor will also have to be called if this is the first time the class is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors actually don't *create* an object. They act more like initializers. They set the data into the objects that are given to them by the JVM.